# I can not display search template created from a post type custom

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I created a Forum plugin and would like to have a cystomized search result template, I added the following excerpt in the plugin execution file:

```
add_filter('single_template', 'pagina_topicos');

function pagina_topicos($single) {
    global $wp_query, $post;

/* Informando o Modelo de Página das Aulas */
if ($post->post_type == "stopicos"){
    if(file_exists(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/single-topico.php'))
        return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/single-topico.php';
}

  if( $wp_query->is_search && $post_type == 'stopicos' )
  {
    return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/archive-stopicos.php';
  }

    return $single;
}
```

I use the following form in the search:

```
 <form role="search" action="<?php echo site_url('/'); ?>" method="get" id="searchform">
                    <input type="text" class="submit-search form-control input-lg" placeholder="Buscar" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="stopicos"/>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="submit" value="Search">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        </button>
                       </form>
```

What can be wrong so that the model I customized is not loaded?

Comment: you check `$post_type`, but where do you set it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `single_template` hook, which is called for a **single** post. From the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template):

> The "single_template" filter can be used to load a custom template for
>   a given post. It will replace the template used whenever the "single"
>   template is called.

My guess is that this can probably be achieved by using the [template_include](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) hook:

> This filter hook is executed immediately before WordPress includes the
>   predetermined template file. This can be used to override WordPress's
>   default template behavior.

Comment: There's also `search_template`, which is specific to just search queries.

Answer (score 0):

Zedejose really worked out with template_include, below what I did and it worked

```
    add_filter('template_include','my_custom_search_template');

function my_custom_search_template($template){
    global $wp_query;
    if (!$wp_query->is_search)
        return $template;

    return dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/search-stopicos.php';

}
```